# List all subroutines in a fortran module

Tags: module, fortran

Is it possible to obtain a list of all functions and sobroutines defined in a fortran module, from within fortran? For example, in python, I can do this:

```
import math
dir(math)
```

and I get a list of all names in the math module. I'm looking for something similar in fortran (I'm not holding my breath, though).

Comment: `grep subroutine filename.f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Outside of "Fortran", some compilers can output symbol tables that could be parsed to obtain this information.  In some cases, the mod file that the compiler generates from compiling the module could itself be parsed.  There are also a number of source code analysis tools that could be adapted.

Comment: So the only option is to write a parser, in some way or other?

Comment: For the specific question you asked - yes.  Whether that's what you have to do to solve the original problem that inspired you to ask that specific question is a different matter - we'd need more information on the original problem for that...

Comment: I was just philosophically thinking about why there isn't a unit test framework for fortran written purely in fortran. For example I've looked at FRUIT, which uses ruby and rakefiles to parse the code and create a fortran file which will run all the tests, and fQunit, which I think uses a C++ parser and makefiles for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In Fortran 90 and later one can use the syntax

function foo()
...
end function foo

and something similar for subroutines. Then one can grep to find function and subroutine names.

Comment: By "grep" I assume you mean from the command line? I would like to do this in a fortran program, that's what I meant by "from within fortran".